# Pandas Store DataFrame when multiple rows are returned by Apply method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Suppose I have a DataFrame as :

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,3,4,5],'name':['A','B','C','D','E']})
```

I want output as :

```
b=pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,1,2,4,3,9,4,16,5,25],'name':['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E']})
```

This is a simple example , what I want to achieve is run **Apply** function on each row of first DataFrame to some function(say func1) which will return 2 rows . Also I need to concat all the returned rows into a single Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can return list of 2 elements and then do [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
a.number = a.number.apply(lambda x: [x, x**2])
print( a.explode('number').reset_index(drop=True) )
```

Prints:

```
  number name
0      1    A
1      1    A
2      2    B
3      4    B
4      3    C
5      9    C
6      4    D
7     16    D
8      5    E
9     25    E
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `apply`, you barely will, `pandas/numpy` suffice for most of our needs with vectorized methods, which are way faster. Apply is basically just a for-loop under the hood.

In this case use `pd.concat` with `Series.pow`:

```
pd.concat([a, a.assign(number=a['number'].pow(2))]).sort_index()

   number name
0       1    A
0       1    A
1       2    B
1       4    B
2       3    C
2       9    C
3       4    D
3      16    D
4       5    E
4      25    E
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way we can use the apply function - for each row we output a DataFrame - after using apply we have a Series of DataFrames, which once we concat, we get the desired result. Thanks to [Hossein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951905/hossein/) for pointing out we wanted to use apply

```
def func(series):
    result = series.copy()
    result[0] = result[0] ** 2
    return pd.concat([series, result], axis=1).T
b = pd.conact(a.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1).to_list())
```

Answer (score -1):

For example if your `func1` could be applied independently to the two columns you could do something like this:

```
def func1(num):
    if isinstance(num, int):
        return num ** 2
    elif isinstance(num, str):
        return num
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid data type")

b = pd.DataFrame()
for col in a.columns:
    transformed_array = [func1(num) for num in a[col]]
    b[col] = np.array(list(zip(a[col], transformed_array))).flatten()
```

If you wanted to do something applied to both:

```
def func1(series):
    return pd.Series([series[0] ** 2, series[1]])

results = []
for idx, row in a.iterrows():
    results.append(row.reset_index(drop=True))
    results.append(func1(row))
b = pd.concat(results, axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)
b.columns = a.columns
```

Probably not the most efficient way to do this but gives you full customisation over the functions you apply to each column. This second way if the columns effected each other you could easily change `func1`

Comment: It seems that the question is about using the `apply` method to achieve this, not using `for` loops to go through the rows as you suggested.